# ShutdownBlockReason works on Windows 7, but not 8

Tags: c#, windows, application-shutdown

Consider the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool blocked = false;
    private string times = "";

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message aMessage)
    {
        const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;
        const int WM_ENDSESSION = 0x0016;

        if (blocked && (aMessage.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION || aMessage.Msg == WM_ENDSESSION))
            return;

        base.WndProc(ref aMessage);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern static bool ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(IntPtr hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszReason);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern static bool ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(IntPtr hWnd);

    string path = "times.txt";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(this.Handle, textBox1.Text))
        {
            blocked = true;

            times += "Creating: " + DateTime.Now + "\r\n";
            File.WriteAllText(path, times);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        times += "About to end: " + DateTime.Now + "\r\n";
        File.WriteAllText(path, times);
        if (ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(this.Handle))
        {
            times += "Ended: " + DateTime.Now + "\r\n";
            File.WriteAllText(path, times);
            blocked = false;
        }
    }    
}
```

Press the button1, and shutdown the system within 10 seconds.

On Windows 7 machine it performs as expected - after powering it on again there's a `times.txt` file with correct times.

On Windows 8 (embedded, and tested it on Windows 10 just for good measure, same result as on 8), this seems to ignore the ShutdownBlockReason functions, as the file `times.txt` only has the `Creating:` line.

Is there some different handling of those methods between those systems that I'm not aware of?